# Calendar and Chat widgets in new Gmail

Tags: gmail, widgets

In Gmail's new look, is it possible to bring back the Chat and Calendar widgets? They are turned on in Settings, but aren't showing. Am I missing something or this is normal behavior for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partly - you can bring them back but not both at the same time it seems. You can display them one at a time by clicking on the Calendar / Gadget icons at the bottom of the left column and resize using the top resize bar.

[image]

Comment: I missed those buttons - same color as the theme. Thanks!